# Slow flicker when video output from DisplayPort to TV HDMI input

Tags: hdmi, tv, displayport

I connected my new laptop (HP EliteBook 8570w running Windows 8.1 Pro) to my 4-year-old Sony HD TV using a DisplayPort to HDMI cable. It almost works. I get a 1920x1080 display, crisp, stable, except that every few seconds or so, the TV image seems to drop out for a couple of seconds (screen goes black). It's almost as if the TV has decided that there is no signal, except that the TV never shows its "no signal" display.

If I use the same cable to connect the laptop to an HD monitor (LG, slightly newer), it works fine. If I connect a different source to the same TV HDMI input (Surface Pro), it also works fine. Seems unique to HDMI out from the HP.

What could be happening over the HDMI connection that the monitor accepts but the TV does not? Is it something that can be resolved by configuration setting? If so, what?

Comment: You've tested that the output and the cable are good, but have you tested another connection to the TV to ensure its input is good?

Comment: Yes, I've used the same HDMI input successfully from a different source.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common problems with converting these types of I/O is the difference of Active vs Passive conversion. Make sure you not only have the proper type of cording and such for one or the other, but that the configuration including drivers are a-okay.